# How to update values in SQL table from pyodbc cursor.execute without hardcoding the value parameters

Tags: python, pyodbc

I want to execute a SQL query and update a table with the value from a sub query.  I know I have to pass values to the "values" parameter of cursor.execute() function but how do I do this if the result is from the query itself.  I could set a user input variable to set this value but I want the whole process to be automated.  The result should be a single integer value.

Is there are way to do this without hardcoding the values?

```
for report in strReportName:
     if report == 'P35 FC Updates':
           cur.execute("""INSERT INTO Elig_Own.DST_Report_Status(TDate, Report, Records, Status)
                        VALUES(CAST(GetDate() AS Date), 'P35 FC Updates', (SELECT MEM_COUNTS FROM Elig_Own.RW_P35_PID WHERE PLAN_ID = '1E'), 'Passed')
                             """)
                            cur.commit()
```

Comment: Are you familiar with the concept of a *parameterized query*?

Comment: No I'd never heard of that.  But It looks like that's what I need to do @Gord Thompson.